# Как сделать, чтобы объект отображался под действием определённого источника света?

Tags: unity3d

Как сделать, чтобы объект отображался под действием определённого источника света? Подобное реализовано в Phasmaphobia. Там отпечатки рук призрака видны, если посветить УФ фонариком

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Могу предложить два способа, один более костыльный, другой как правильно**.
Первый это сделать коллайдер в форме конуса(если это spotlight) и привязать его к источнику света. Проверять коллайдер на наличие объекта и если тот в нём есть, то включать у объекта render.
Второй это raycast от источника света и проверять столкнулся ли он с объектом, если так, то включать render у объекта. Только проблема в том, что эти два способа отобразят объект полностью, независимо от того попадает на него часть света или весь.